# Filter out nodes that refer to a specific kind of node

Tags: drupal, view, cck

I have a node type (reviews) that uses CCK to refer to another kind of node (either books or videos). Is there a way for me to use Views so that I can show only Reviews of Books or only Reviews of Videos?

I've tried creating a Relationship in the View and using a parameter, but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get my client to agree to a change, so that each node gets a radio button to mark what kind of review it is. That means that users will have to select the book/video and then say which type it is, but they are college-educated and hopefully this won't be beyond them.

So then I can add the review type into my Filters, and show only book reviews or video reviews that way. I suspect that my initial question is impossible without a lot of hacking.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a CCK node reference field? If so this documentation may help get you started: http://drupal.org/node/289738

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'm checking it out.

Comment: That link was interesting and educational (there are areas of Views that are still mostly mysterious to me), but didn't exactly answer my question. Anyway, I've been able work around the issue. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Views 3, which may not be a solution for you at all. :/

You add a required relationship based on your node reference, and then add a filter on node type of book/movie. The filter's 'Use relationship' should be set to the required relationship you set up previously.

Comment: Thanks, but Views 3 is not an option right now. Good to know that for future projects, though.